# chrome-remote-desktop Installation error under Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chrome, google

My vps can't install chrome-remote-desktop under ubuntu 22.04 LTS, which reported installation error.
Does anyone has the same error or any solutions?

I've reinstalled the system, so there are some relationship with the linux images or configuration. However, it's strange that the error didn't exist in the other vps instances.

My recent installation error under Ubuntu 22.04 reports like this:

chrome-remote-desktop :

Depends: python (>= 2.6) but it is not installable

Depends: python-psutil but it is not installable

Recommends: xvfb-randr but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.